# Void Linux hangs on poweroff

Tags: linux, acpi, runit, void-linux

I just got a Oryx Pro, model Oryp4, from System76 and installed [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org/) on it. When I try to power it off or reboot I just get [these messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJln.jpg) and [this dmesg](http://ix.io/1zog).

I have tried adding acpi=off to /etc/default/grub on the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT . When I run

> sudo poweroff

the machine it hangs on

> reboot: System halted.

Comment: Upgrade the BIOS/firmware.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown;  note the `-h` and `-H` and `-P` options.  How are you shutting down?  And if your *Systemd* based then the shutdown or init commands may not directly apply but they typically map to corresponding systemd service.

Comment: Void Linux: *We use runit as the init system and service supervisor.  runit is a simple and effective approach to initialize the system with reliable service supervision. See the usage page for a brief introduction.  Not a fork, Void Linux is an independent distribution, developed entirely by volunteers.*  Being what it is, would not surprise me if it's a Void Linux problem/bug,

Comment: Did it do it on reboot as well?

Answer (score 0):

After submitting a ticket to System76 they told me to install the latest NVIDIA drivers and it goes through poweroff normall.